# Validar select ajax

Tags: ajax

Estoy intentado validar que el select con ajax no este vació pero no encuentro la forma, he probado de varias maneras pero nada.

```
            <form method="post" id="formulario">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="form" id="form">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" id="options" value="enviar" class="btn btn-danger" />
                </div>
            </form>
<div id="resultado"></div>

    <script>
    $(document).on('ready',function(){

      $('#report').click(function(){
        var url = "documento.php";
if($("#form").val() == 0) {
    alert("Debe Seleccionar una opcion");
    return false;
}
        $.ajax({                        
           type: "POST",                 
           url: url,                    
           data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
           success: function(data)            
           {
             $("#formulario").hide();
             $('#resultado').html(data);           
           }
         });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

De las múltiples formas el ajax lo ignora y me realiza la petición en vacio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo propondría una solución más o menos así:

- Ponemos en el `select` un primer valor por defecto con un texto que puede ser indicativo de la acción que realiza dicho elemento.
- Ponemos por defecto el botón enviar desactivado, así evitamos acciones innecesarias del usuario.
- Escuchamos el evento `change` del `select` y activamos el botón solamente cuando no esté seleccionada la opción por defecto.
- Escuchamos por otra parte los clicks del botón.

Es una solución elegante. Es como suelen funcionar la mayoría de formularios que usamos en línea y que no nos dejan enviar hasta que no hemos completado todo lo que se requiere.

Cabe decir que esta solución se puede implementar también para grupos de elementos que sean requeridos en un formulario.

```js
$('#mSelect').on('change', function(e) {
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  var valueSelected = this.value;
  var selectStatus = (valueSelected == 0) ? true : false;
  console.log(selectStatus);
  $('#options').prop('disabled', selectStatus);
});

$('#options').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Aquí todo el código que escucha los clicks del botón");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="formulario">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="form" id="mSelect">
      <option value="0">-Seleccione-</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="options" value="enviar" class="btn btn-danger" disabled/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Pues me ha servido la opción no lo había pensado pensé que era más bien un error mio en el ajax que otra cosa.

Muchas gracias ;)

Comment: @A.Cedano Como podría hacer esto:  Cabe decir que esta solución se puede implementar también para grupos de elementos que sean requeridos en un formulario

Comment: @Cesarin se podría por ejemplo asignar una clase a esos elementos y emprender acciones conjuntas sobre dichos elementos basándose en esa clase. Te recomiendo que plantees una pregunta con tu duda, mostrando lo que quieres lograr, el código que tiene y los eventuales problemas, así tendrás la ayuda de varios usuarios hasta encontrar una solución óptima.

Comment: @A. Cedano, Que tal buenos dias, ya estuve implementando tu código, y de manera aislada funciona correctamente para cada combox select,  pero necesito que me funcione en cascada para entre 3 a 5 combox select para que los valores que se envian por Ajax no vayan vacios y se ejecute correctamente la consulta, ya expuse el tema pero no ha recibido respuesta, y ya le di vueltas a muchas posibles soluciones y lo mas cercano a algo ya mas funcional es tu código

Comment: @A.Cedano : Esta es la entrada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371835/como-validar-unos-combox-select-dentro-a-la-par-de-una-peticion-ajax

Answer (score 0):

El valor del select no seleccionado es "nada" no 0, cambia eso y prueba quizás te pueda servir.

Algo como preguntar si viene un valor para el id "Form".

Comment: El id es para asociarlo y si probé también con valor vació pero el ajax lo ignora del igual modo y procesa la solicitud.